# CSS Animation on multiple properties

Tags: css-animations

I would like to animate an element's bottom position and opacity simultaneously using CSS keyframes.

My element opacity is animating but the bottom position does not.

```
.custom-fade-down{
-webkit-animation: 23s ease 0s normal forwards 1 custom-down;
-moz-animation: 23s ease 0s normal forwards 1 custom-down;
    animation: 23s ease 0s normal forwards 1 custom-down;
}

@keyframes custom-down {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        bottom: 10px;
    }

    to {
        opacity: 1;
        bottom: 1px;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution is close. Adding a `position: relative;` to the `.custom-fade-down` class should do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution is close. Add a `position: relative;` to the `.custom-fade-down` class so the `bottom` prop takes effect.

```js
$('div').addClass('custom-fade-down');
```

```css
.custom-fade-down {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  bottom: -100px;
  background-color: black;
  -webkit-animation: 23s ease 0s normal forwards 1 custom-down;
  -moz-animation: 23s ease 0s normal forwards 1 custom-down;
  animation: 23s ease 0s normal forwards 1 custom-down;
}

@keyframes custom-down {
  from {
    opacity: 0;
    bottom: -100px;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 1;
    bottom: 0px;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="position: relative;"></div>
```

Comment: I am dynamically adding this class using jQuery to an element that already has a relative position. Should I remove the relative position from the element and put it on the class instead?

Comment: Either method should work. I've updated the example above to add the class when on load. And would agree it's cleaner to add the `position: relative;` to the class itself.